# How to create custom paper size in laser printer by vb6 or visual basic 2005 dynamically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have problem in setting the Custom paper size in Laser Printer. I don't know to set custom paper size in Laser Printer by code dynamically  by vb-6 or visual studio 2005.

Thanks for advance if any one can help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you are asking. If you need more help update your questions.

But in vb.net (VS 2005) you would do it like this

```
Dim pkCustomSize1 As New PaperSize("Custom Paper Size", 100, 200)
```

Here is a link to the MSDN page about papersize https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.papersize(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I want to know that how to create custom paper size in laser printer by vb 6 or vs 2005

Comment: I don't understand that's what I answered

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried various ways... and I found this and it allows me to print A6 paper size... before that, although I had set the A6 paper size, but it will print A6 size in A4 paper size.. here is little addition, in PrintButton... at ***printersetting.defaultpagesetting***

```
PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()
        PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = New Printing.PaperSize("A6", 410, 580)
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0
        PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings
```

(google translation)